# How do you call a class that uses generic types in java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble calling my SelectionSort class, which is listed below. I get an error "cannot access SelectionSort." I'm trying to see how long the SelectionSort class takes to sort a random array. Here is the SelectionSort class:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SelectionSort {

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    selectionSort(a, a.length-1);
  }


  private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(T[] a, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return;
    int indMax = findMaxIndex(a, n);
    swap(a, n, indMax);
    selectionSort(a, n-1);
  }

  private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int findMaxIndex(T[] a, int n) {
    int indMax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (a[indMax].compareTo(a[i]) < 0) {
        indMax = i;
      }
    }
    return indMax;
  }

  private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void swap(T[] a, int i, int j) {
    T tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
  }

  // Main function to test the code
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Make an array of Integer objects
    Integer[] a = new Integer[4];
    a[0] = new Integer(2);
    a[1] = new Integer(1);
    a[2] = new Integer(4);
    a[3] = new Integer(3);

    // Call the sorting method (type T will be instantiated to Integer)
    SelectionSort.sort(a);

    // Print the result
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      System.out.println(a[i].toString());
  }
}
```

Here is the part of the code where I try to call the class, I get the error in the second line

```
      long result;

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      SelectionSort.sort(array,  100,  array.length-1);
      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      result = endTime-startTime; 

      System.out.println("The quick sort runtime is " + result + " miliseconds");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in the second line of the second piece of code, when I try to call the class

Comment: And where is that code located?

Comment: Also, what is `array`?

Comment: I don't see a `SelectionSort.sort()` method with three arguments. There's just the one with one argument.  Are you trying to sort a subarray of `array`?  I suspect this question has nothing at all to do with generics.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I made some more edits to try and make it more clear

Comment: @JudgeMental Basically what I'm asking is how do I call the SelectionSort.sort() method, as when I try to do it, I get an error saying "cannot access SelectionSort." Sorry for the bad wording.

Comment: Show us the package declaration at the top of the SelectionSort class, and the package and import declarations in the timeQuickSort class.  If they aren't in the same package, you have to import the SelectionSort class to be able to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectionSort.sort(array, 100, array.length-1);
```

This 3-argument method doesn't exist in the code you've shown us so presumably you can't call it.

```
int[] array = new int[size];
```

`int` is not an object so it can't extend `Comparable`. Arrays do not get auto-boxed so you must declare it as an `Integer[]` to pass it to a method that accepts a `T[]` where `T extends Comparable<T>`.

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[4];
SelectionSort.sort(a);
```

That part was OK and that is how you can call `sort`.